# Selenium click on div text that is a variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an array of strings that varies and some strings have an apostrophe

```
array = ["It's a Joke", "It's not a Joke","No more Jokes please"]
strNo = 0
if (strNo == 0):
    rpstring = array[strNo]
    print(f'"""//div[text()="{rpstring}"]"""')
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,f'"""//div[text()="{rpstring}"]"""')))
    button.click()
```

Here is the print result

```
"""//div[text()="It's a Joke"]"""
```

I like to be able to click the element based on the text passed as it may vary.
Current I have the print result here but it fails because i believe the apostrophe is messing up string and I am not sure I am setting the string properly and its not being found in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `contains` try with below and I also removed the extra quotes `"` from `xpath` that might causing the issue

```
array = ["It's a Joke", "It's not a Joke","No more Jokes please"]
strNo = 0
if strNo == 0:
    rpstring = array[strNo]
    button_xpath = f"//div[contains(text(), '{rpstring}')]"
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath)))
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Element not found after 10 seconds.")
```